# My gpu doesn't supports cycles but it rendered succesfuly. How can it be?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I had intel hd 4600 gpu which doesn't support Cycles rendering but, out of curiosity, l tried and it worked. How is this possible?

As I know my laptop only had one gpu.

Comment: ⏳ ...  ...    Certain computations will be slower.  The bigger the computation the larger the difference in time will be measured.  Large Simulations such a fluid and others will be slower.

Comment: i able to run ocean simulation perfectly why it isn't slow on 6 year old laptop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you specifically change it, Cycles will render with the CPU by default.  CPU will almost always work, but it will probably be slower due to not having the massive parallelization that GPU's have.

[image: Cycles options window, showing Cycles, supported mode, and CPU rendering]

If you are using GPU and it is working, Blender not supporting a GPU specifically doesn't mean it won't work, it just isn't guaranteed to work well.